# Small Circles in Super Large Circle

Tags: css

My goal is to ensure the outer circle is
always a perfect circle but covers the
whole web browser.

( adjusts automatically to the web browser re-size )

http://cssdeck.com/labs/npogghyl

the inside rings need to distribute themselves
in an even manner within the outer circle

( if evenly is too difficult .. they should at least not be hidden within the outer circle for now )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think is will be possible with CSS alone:

So here is some jQuery:

```
function resize() {
  var size = Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height());
  $('.a1').height(size);
  $('.a1').width(size);
}
$(resize);
$(window).resize(resize);
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ptqgzf1p